# Fail with error 'ERC721: transfer caller is not owner nor approved' with Open Zeppelin IERC721.transferFrom()

Tags: solidity, web3js, nft, openzeppelin

I am using the IERC721.transferFrom() openZeppelin interface. When I try to transfer the NFT from msg.sender(me) to the contract (address.(this)) I get a `Fail with error 'ERC721: transfer caller is not owner nor approved'` error. I am trying to list an NFT to my marketplace without having to do multiple transactions. What am I missing?

```
contract Market is OwnableUpgradeable, ReentrancyGuardUpgradeable {
 function _createListing(
    address nftAddress,
    uint256 tokenId,
    address _listingTokenAddress,
    string calldata _listingTokenName,
    string calldata _listingTokenSymbol,
    uint256 price,
    uint256 expiration
) internal {
    require(nftAddress != address(0), "zero address");
    require(price > 0, "zero amount");
    IERC721Upgradeable(nftAddress).transferFrom( //<-- Issue line
        msg.sender,
        address(this),
        tokenId
    );
    PropertyListing memory _propertyListing = PropertyListing(
        nftAddress,
        tokenId,
        price,
        _listingTokenAddress,
        _listingTokenName,
        _listingTokenSymbol,
        msg.sender,
        expiration,
        true,
        false
    );
    listings.push(_propertyListing);
    uint256 _id = listings.length - 1;
    emit NewPropertyListing(
        _id,
        nftAddress,
        tokenId,
        price,
        _listingTokenAddress,
        _listingTokenName,
        _listingTokenSymbol,
        msg.sender,
        expiration,
        true,
        false
    );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `transferFrom()` function, a user must to approve your smart contract to move his token. And only if user has approved this operation you can called `_createListing()` from your smart contract.
In your case, a user must to call `approve()` function from nft smart contract address with this parameters:

- to: your smart contract address;
- tokenId: token that must to move into your smart contract.

After this operation, you can call `_createListing()` function.